# DKIM FAIL with domain null after passed through relay

Tags: email, dkim

I use smtpd and dkimproxy to send DKIM-signed mail. Yesterday, I could send to an @email.arizona.edu address (which uses google for the web client, not sure about the server) and the DKIM passed. Today, mail to @email.arizona.edu fails with DKIM domain null, although you can see the DKIM passed for the first server in both cases. As far as I can tell, my mail configuration hasn't changed.

Here are the two messages:

to @email.arizona.edu **PASS**

```
Delivered-To: OMITTED@uits.arizona.edu
Received: by 10.103.123.134 with SMTP id w128csp715815vsc;
        Sat, 3 Jun 2017 16:46:22 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.157.31.71 with SMTP id x7mr9128991otx.249.1496533581972;
        Sat, 03 Jun 2017 16:46:21 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1496533581; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=xBBQXMyGqxcXlr5lRcFi3hZVjTpQ9AKKPsv4QOvfmwEm74bRBHBChy/D/N9lzAkobC
         ZNleVn/igqFJ9kOaUfZJDl7BY2BTPLM+K9dlfg1hkKTVVztiHk7q/up0F6nAxnQHq/Kd
         FV216x8yRTL1yyI0xBfTaWCESM+rcSSB/sWutmHUiEfVllo2w8zn7UGnnjpOD6EZCMng
         nmyK/zSVUgRQ/dbnC8YLYjLH2ikKJX29BpmRjKVFZcHUyhRuIZTxzkXdOoSallEE6Z3h
         iHIYOmP74+ghPmZzl9ZtNNcsQy1ftODgHazFvQw14KqMh/6laECHjR2ops6HDx/mbHey
         qAGw==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=message-id:subject:to:date:from:domainkey-signature:dkim-signature
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=q5uymabsG2K4XiWUfU06GzH1QEleobnrtk35/WomHas=;
        b=MC3wk4Wz6ri9lQ7nCwUe+Uyk1s7nq8gZ5ZJkJZBxw+lklS2tbXsXcqw0EVLt9VsOxJ
         psPOHC4+iRJo0McW6EM2zARf9RlzOINmXm75kugnk5HbhlBWvcYwmNpINJHBFZdXlfcg
         QoDfa1h8pvphRQyyTwIol8fGgMIJ/kWeyBOTWa9O1jXQYYC8aLUcmCpxKfnwnAisOcgx
         3mjYNZ4lZNnINjnWpXhgzXRB8LuqY9gvr2/jo4PTuORFWni6SzOLPwG+OKm61PsBS0zK
         WnQXgXDP/hnR+lI2pJ820Qk/fYvTvZzSlBTD9PM3d4KobkswgAdfs6LYTcdFa9gD7Hrv
         0YAw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@EXAMPLE.COM;
       spf=fail (google.com: domain of dillon@EXAMPLE.COM does not designate 128.196.130.120 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=dillon@EXAMPLE.COM
Return-Path: <dillon@EXAMPLE.COM>
Received: from mailgator.email.arizona.edu (mailgator-s1-n1.email.arizona.edu. [128.196.130.201])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id p5si1155840oic.247.2017.06.03.16.46.21
        for <OMITTED@uits.arizona.edu>;
        Sat, 03 Jun 2017 16:46:21 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of dillon@EXAMPLE.COM does not designate 128.196.130.120 as permitted sender) client-ip=128.196.130.120;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@EXAMPLE.COM;
       spf=fail (google.com: domain of dillon@EXAMPLE.COM does not designate 128.196.130.120 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=dillon@EXAMPLE.COM
Received: from mails2n2-route0.email.arizona.edu (mails2n2-route0.email.arizona.edu [128.196.130.120]) by mailgator.email.arizona.edu (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 441FA12094D for <OMITTED@email.arizona.edu>; Sat,
  3 Jun 2017 16:46:21 -0700 (MST)
Received-SPF: Pass (mails2n2in.email.arizona.edu: domain of
  dillon@EXAMPLE.COM designates MY.IP.ADDRESS as permitted
  sender) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=MY.IP.ADDRESS;
  receiver=mails2n2in.email.arizona.edu;
  envelope-from="dillon@EXAMPLE.COM";
  x-sender="dillon@EXAMPLE.COM"; x-conformance=spf_only;
  x-record-type="v=spf1"
Received-SPF: Pass (mails2n2in.email.arizona.edu: domain of
  postmaster@EXAMPLE.COM designates MY.IP.ADDRESS as permitted
  sender) identity=helo; client-ip=MY.IP.ADDRESS;
  receiver=mails2n2in.email.arizona.edu;
  envelope-from="dillon@EXAMPLE.COM";
  x-sender="postmaster@EXAMPLE.COM"; x-conformance=spf_only;
  x-record-type="v=spf1"
Authentication-Results: mails2n2in.email.arizona.edu; dkim=pass (signature verified) header.i=@EXAMPLE.COM
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Filtered: true
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result: A0B3VwC2STNZXSBHTy1cDoN6kG6PJ08BgSEcAVmWehIciQZEEwECAQEBAQEBAQYaFl2FXwMBNgEiegYOBIpFrHGDEIMJBwKIIAEIhmCDToJrg32FJ5E8jG4Ogm6SLQGQBQiEe49kN4EqgQmEfAELAYIFXiCKJAEBAQ
X-IPAS-Result: A0B3VwC2STNZXSBHTy1cDoN6kG6PJ08BgSEcAVmWehIciQZEEwECAQEBAQEBAQYaFl2FXwMBNgEiegYOBIpFrHGDEIMJBwKIIAEIhmCDToJrg32FJ5E8jG4Ogm6SLQGQBQiEe49kN4EqgQmEfAELAYIFXiCKJAEBAQ
X-IronPort-AV: E=Sophos;i="5.39,293,1493708400";
    d="scan'208";a="185041594"
Received: from EXAMPLE.COM ([MY.IP.ADDRESS])
  by mails2n2in.email.arizona.edu with ESMTP/TLS/DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA; 03 Jun 2017 16:46:20 -0700
Received: from EXAMPLE.COM (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by EXAMPLE.COM (OpenSMTPD) with ESMTP id 2ce206bf for <OMITTED@email.arizona.edu>; Sat, 3 Jun 2017 16:46:19 -0700 (MST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed; d=EXAMPLE.COM; h=from:date :to:subject:message-id; s=default; bh=SL7XWS6OwbKllWPXEFaWcnPdg2 I=; b=kM8o8rKbfXXTFXshpqZ11hIFlBfESsDjNYQjDBLJvGqkH5CvUtIBlAUbe1 hyQi1Wkrl/sMmy+q9aCSEceIUR/pZpiwnIjK7IPx/czfl+jOmj+I9KYca+9ryWs2 Imyd4xJMdhy9iQnw0qwxt+x/KVjSYAMNPSpFvqqdI1Yi4fuVZ2FcksbhsUJDYmZS bAVpPHle5Q4wLtXYLW80iMZJCqJ3CWwhn/37/UNSfVhqyVS/oI6nKKKkC1RHjliH O7I+JiFBIqWtPzBHlqS3wo9/Sd9rb1a4QsnysR8MMLBSlV8hkaBtK5Hv+ZPpsu0S VhxEC4xsMemkoyf0cLff18osICTg==
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; d=EXAMPLE.COM; h=from:date :to:subject:message-id; q=dns; s=default; b=uIdxdpQuS7UPQZiTWiG7 C7pSEjYQt/L/AFVp/R1PFYfUwtn7hs69qioUuZFQBtb0m5e0VwK+iaGm2CCFqkyB ZB5e81DqJteWXSTwIxqdkri06EfX8SfAESNYzn8552+mHqgbIObVv/zoyYEU7xQV HnIHrTztuJd2r9SCa4eIWcGd7hX31ayFV6VEvQmetW/zwoe2qG/s9dn5B/vgxGsU 3OihHQoAw1I5NOIuQp9t2mxO4YnEo5oXVzQk7un6lHijmlTh5vUy70vrgConRTyz 6GAC8H2TzQUSadeEH41gEXpdJnlFnLO/koMIGsFCaa8ACrOj4X3MrUy1Bqxmt2/+ Qg==
Received: from localhost (EXAMPLE.COM [local]) by EXAMPLE.COM (OpenSMTPD) with ESMTPA id f31a68c5 for <OMITTED@email.arizona.edu>; Sat, 3 Jun 2017 16:46:19 -0700 (MST)
From: dillon <dillon@EXAMPLE.COM>
Date: Sat, 3 Jun 2017 16:46:19 -0700 (MST)
To: OMITTED@email.arizona.edu
Subject: aa
Message-Id: <fcf056bab43647d7@EXAMPLE.COM>

blah
```

to @email.arizona.edu **FAIL**

```
Delivered-To: OMITTED@uits.arizona.edu
Received: by 10.103.123.134 with SMTP id w128csp937111vsc;
        Sun, 4 Jun 2017 08:43:08 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.157.89.137 with SMTP id u9mr1833275oth.215.1496590988912;
        Sun, 04 Jun 2017 08:43:08 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1496590988; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=SMM/PXFQ0wEyanWczeT8/5DxRmsvNbt9nOHL8WhXO8K/jLX1KGnoS1yUmk5hm/iJ4D
         snmX8AW3cDt7sglNL359IUhaUC3pPGeSDBptV2CayPs3V1zhg3MpHSQWSNp6If2GZdim
         T/S5o+EowD+LXGKlNoPq6bjLpB9R+C/lBHMyaYbhPtLGb/UWIOBZqJReNwDRJ7tcJnAB
         laZCoa6bwxOwRhuaC7dZ0NEgX6mnQ2la/SdFzimbz+a0D1FLjVelajyRW0bCMtDr6km1
         MHM/QFZtH/z7aeWlmPB1/KZL7dH/BlvsxQZxmh+iLfbhKI34cOE7O/JHyk0+Iqr/wEp5
         yI0g==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=message-id:to:date:from:domainkey-signature:dkim-signature:subject
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=lQFy4p37ps8+tOt10kWiXLaKWWNB0sstf/sQoBSjwU0=;
        b=BiqDhgKw90O99XpHuvbPtFhsg6WE/J/N0MUj+MqYYBffI6r/EcL+SFSSsDSLin2ugL
         KZ0bfpHCpfCptkQ+pvA/RXiDecTo6x1KxLNxBYkLvHD2MMBCtGiT8D8PjAT1KZ7KNGk7
         XEN5SXyMaPtPKR3cdKp4plGXRuE8iJsJmK1neTIE5RNwXDIOYeUk36toLkgQvequLW5O
         6GM0m2VfG8ng900vTD6TECVHK1bYl3y/MWMqzfwGoWOtxrKS6lenHRoKpTSjh2KgDXsu
         PhvZKNdYKi892xR3gHFVVDCSG0Gze9vRE1GgjQtSwXcUJR0/ELyCQQWOgiYht27DyEC0
         LDdA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=fail header.i=@EXAMPLE.COM;
       spf=fail (google.com: domain of dillon@EXAMPLE.COM does not designate 128.196.130.69 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=dillon@EXAMPLE.COM
Return-Path: <dillon@EXAMPLE.COM>
Received: from mailgator.email.arizona.edu (mailgator-s1-n1.email.arizona.edu. [128.196.130.201])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id d125si11748533oia.150.2017.06.04.08.43.08
        for <OMITTED@uits.arizona.edu>;
        Sun, 04 Jun 2017 08:43:08 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of dillon@EXAMPLE.COM does not designate 128.196.130.69 as permitted sender) client-ip=128.196.130.69;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=fail header.i=@EXAMPLE.COM;
       spf=fail (google.com: domain of dillon@EXAMPLE.COM does not designate 128.196.130.69 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=dillon@EXAMPLE.COM
Received: from mails1n0-route0.email.arizona.edu (mails1n0-route0.email.arizona.edu [128.196.130.69]) by mailgator.email.arizona.edu (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 70E2D120967 for <OMITTED@email.arizona.edu>; Sun,
  4 Jun 2017 08:43:08 -0700 (MST)
Received-SPF: Pass (mails1n0in.email.arizona.edu: domain of
  dillon@EXAMPLE.COM designates MY.IP.ADDRESS as permitted
  sender) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=MY.IP.ADDRESS;
  receiver=mails1n0in.email.arizona.edu;
  envelope-from="dillon@EXAMPLE.COM";
  x-sender="dillon@EXAMPLE.COM"; x-conformance=spf_only;
  x-record-type="v=spf1"
Received-SPF: Pass (mails1n0in.email.arizona.edu: domain of
  postmaster@EXAMPLE.COM designates MY.IP.ADDRESS as permitted
  sender) identity=helo; client-ip=MY.IP.ADDRESS;
  receiver=mails1n0in.email.arizona.edu;
  envelope-from="dillon@EXAMPLE.COM";
  x-sender="postmaster@EXAMPLE.COM"; x-conformance=spf_only;
  x-record-type="v=spf1"
Authentication-Results: mails1n0in.email.arizona.edu; dkim=pass (signature verified) header.i=@EXAMPLE.COM
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Filtered: true
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result: A0DEoAAhKjRZXSBHTy1dDoN6gR6PUI8mTwGBIRwBkEuFC4F9EhyJBkgPAQIBAQEBAQEBBhoWXYU4JwMBNgEiegYOBIpFrQ2DEIMJBwKIHgEIhmCDToZohSeRPIxuDoJuki0BkA0elEFJA4EVgQmEfAELAYIFXiCKWAEBAQ
X-IPAS-Result: A0DEoAAhKjRZXSBHTy1dDoN6gR6PUI8mTwGBIRwBkEuFC4F9EhyJBkgPAQIBAQEBAQEBBhoWXYU4JwMBNgEiegYOBIpFrQ2DEIMJBwKIHgEIhmCDToZohSeRPIxuDoJuki0BkA0elEFJA4EVgQmEfAELAYIFXiCKWAEBAQ
Subject: [SPAM?] teste
X-IronPort-AV: E=Sophos;i="5.39,296,1493708400";
    d="scan'208";a="205331245"
Received: from EXAMPLE.COM ([MY.IP.ADDRESS])
  by mails1n0in.email.arizona.edu with ESMTP/TLS/DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA; 04 Jun 2017 08:43:07 -0700
Received: from EXAMPLE.COM (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by EXAMPLE.COM (OpenSMTPD) with ESMTP id 22b5b79c for <OMITTED@email.arizona.edu>; Sun, 4 Jun 2017 08:43:07 -0700 (MST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed; d=EXAMPLE.COM; h=from:date :to:subject:message-id; s=default; bh=txH7JSSG7N9u9U+yve1yUm32EA U=; b=K8yvihgFvCzdVXoAeW7eF8EfMxW6/aweOmL6XbLL+d8hoolXYsWGh9agql bj+Q7YsoW4OCOLudtMZIzW9VWLaQPWMZ8hIHArok2jri00FsYs2pSY00aVMhK7O3 tKzSlgIUp9or7gefUs5xostl+bMM9b7Z0LrbQogJw2XVLydf9wMB+UYgk8CK7O7b cEyaBDCejp/DLXXdmYK1rtKG0aigxIw7jple57aGnHsirW4dIn8i63IMbOynFcce UetCfZ6FK6wsggLuB7WXs40stIR4yKU1LtPcGlhiCzfIiSkFUDhhACxt71nQ6p7R Se6D637KV6ri+RfBsETUc2xXgjFQ==
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; d=EXAMPLE.COM; h=from:date :to:subject:message-id; q=dns; s=default; b=NKlu8RpigBoJzEgnN1fb OB7oVKuczGcw53YeDk5nwJhtKjkSlayFXYGvVcJC44ubVWWWm3iquw1XBmqxK9z9 efwX1ZQmkKzN+Y/w81Fk+R6q79G6b5B1vQBzEY+biIK4V1qEATEXtIT+lW7ss1CL z5oK4u+4LKcl+MO8Hg+0+IgCVSyxFXcL0z3Xt61qt4YKPFN8sEAWkNLCfxQlnWrQ rCu9U6DZoTLE987IQisI5MUpTA1JpSc3W6vbcptT4mANsfmD/JRsD3+RuknE76pJ KhlDTaFuk7TBhSUfKM0HqPpWZr+eqCS7bUtViHhm6V+4Di5vGtmUwGFAcNBY9kkp LA==
Received: from localhost (EXAMPLE.COM [local]) by EXAMPLE.COM (OpenSMTPD) with ESMTPA id 80e6e692 for <OMITTED@email.arizona.edu>; Sun, 4 Jun 2017 08:43:07 -0700 (MST)
From: dillon <dillon@EXAMPLE.COM>
Date: Sun, 4 Jun 2017 08:43:07 -0700 (MST)
To: OMITTED@email.arizona.edu
Message-Id: <8e72453d4274dede@EXAMPLE.COM>

testa
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to stay sure that is working,
please check this [link](http://www.appmaildev.com/en/dkim) then just click Next and send an email from the domain that you wanna test you will get an immediate feedback about it.

You need to be sure internal and public Key in the DNS match to achieve your goals, so check the internal and external DNS set up to match.

Also, make sure that relay doesn't remove any headers, look for the option to preserve the headers.

Comment: SPF and DKIM pass. And the relay that seems to be causing problems isn't mine. You can see my email passes through mails1n0-route0.email.arizona.edu (not mine) then mailgator.email.arizona.edu (also not mine), and it looks like in both cases the "route" server recognized DKIM as passing, but in only one case the "mailgator" server did. I've continued to send emails to the email.arizona.edu, and usually DKIM fails but it randomly passes sometimes.

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure that the error is not on your site, if you try the link above you get always pass?
you can see the MX of the mailgator and check if there are more than one (that it should be). If anything you can always give them a call and troubleshoot your issue with your provider.

Comment: Yes, it consistently passes. Same for the gmail.com domain, DKIM (and SPF) always passes. I might not totally get what you're saying about the MX. The MX record for email.arizona.edu is apparently just mailgator.email.arizona.edu whose IP address changes occasionally. I'll see if I can find who to contact. Thanks for the help